# CSS backgrounds and color not reflecting in HTML page

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

Hi I have an HTML file and a Stylesheet file for the aesthetics, im keeping this HTML in google app scripts. so when i deploy the app, the backgrounds are not getting styled

my code.gs is like this

```
    function doGet(request) {
```

`return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')`
`.evaluate();`
`}`

`function include(filename) {`
`return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)`
`.getContent();`
`}`

My html script goes like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
 <head>    
   <base target="_top">
   <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>    
<body>    
    <h2>Login Page</h2><br>    
    <div class="login">    
    <form id="login" method="get" action="login.php">    
        <label><b>User Name     
        </b>    
        </label>    
        <input type="text" name="Uname" id="Uname" placeholder="Username">    
        <br><br>    
        <label><b>Password     
        </b>    
        </label>    
        <input type="Password" name="Pass" id="Pass" placeholder="Password">    
        <br><br>    
        <input type="button" name="log" id="log" value="Log In Here">       
        <br><br>    
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">    
        <span>Remember me</span>    
        <br><br>    
        Forgot <a href="#">Password</a>    
    </form>     
</div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

and css goes like this

```
    <style>

body  
{  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;  
    background-color:#6abadeba;  
    font-family: 'Arial';  
}  
.login{  
        width: 382px;  
        overflow: hidden;  
        margin: auto;  
        margin: 20 0 0 450px;  
        padding: 80px;  
        background: #23463f;  
        border-radius: 15px ;  
          
}  
h2{  
    text-align: center;  
    color: #277582;  
    padding: 20px;  
}  
label{  
    color: #08ffd1;  
    font-size: 17px;  
}  
#Uname{  
    width: 300px;  
    height: 30px;  
    border: none;  
    border-radius: 3px;  
    padding-left: 8px;  
}  
#Pass{  
    width: 300px;  
    height: 30px;  
    border: none;  
    border-radius: 3px;  
    padding-left: 8px;  
      
}  
#log{  
    width: 300px;  
    height: 30px;  
    border: none;  
    border-radius: 17px;  
    padding-left: 7px;  
    color: blue;  
  
  
}  
span{  
    color: white;  
    font-size: 17px;  
}  
a{  
    float: right;  
    background-color: grey;  
}  
    <style>
```

what could be going wrong?

when i deploy, browser shows this
[image: Browser]

I did debug checking if style sheet is included or not
i was following this guide
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#page.html

Comment: I think that in your showing CSS, the last `<style>` should be `</style>`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current scripts. How about this?

Comment: @tanaike i have changed to </style> but still i dont get the background colors or anythin specified in stylesheet.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `i have changed to </style> but still i dont get the background colors or anythin specified in stylesheet.html`, when I tested your script by modifying the last `<style>` to `</style>`, I can confirm your CSS is reflected in the HTML. So, for example, after you modified the last `<style>` to `</style>`, how about redeploying Web Apps and test it again?

Comment: @tanaike i redeployed and tested still same

Comment: @Tanaike i think issue is related to google aps, can you dry to deploy from your side?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, I think that it is required to know your actual situation because when I tested your script, your CSS worked. So, can you share your Google Apps Script project for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike form id="login" method="get" action="login.php"> does this line has anything to do with php?

Comment: @Tanaike sure i can share, but i tink i need your email

Comment: @Tanaike this is the link https://script.google.com/d/1yJbQPwRzacCqQt57Bis855YgVzTW1J5YuhYsP28FVuU6kKR5vZmuJkdC/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You body background color seems incorrect to me too many characters

Comment: Your last style tag is still wrong in your question

Comment: @cooper i changed the background color and styling  background-color:#ff6347; and  a{  
        float: right;  
        background-color: grey;  
    }  
    </style> but still not working

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing your Google Apps Script project. When I saw it, I noticed that you are using `U+00A0` (no-break space) as the space. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, it was required to directly check your Google Apps Script project. So, please modify this to `U+0020` and test it again. For example, please copy and paste the HTML, CSS from your question to your Google Apps Script project and test it again. When I tested this, I confirmed your CSS is reflected.

Comment: When you copy and paste the HTML and CSS from your question, please be careful about the last `<style>`.

Comment: @Tanaike i did try copying the code but im facing same issue.. and how to change U+00A0 to U+0020 ??

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `i did try copying the code but im facing same issue.`, I think that in this case, my proposed situation is not changed. So, please modify the spaces in HTML and CSS from `U+00A0` to `U+0020`? For this, about `how to change U+00A0 to U+0020 ??`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I have already proposed about this. In this case, how about directly copying and pasting HTML and CSS from your question to your project?

Comment: @Tanaike i copied and did paste, i think its not changing can you change and save the project?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `can you change and save the project?`, unfortunately, I cannot edit your project, because I have no permission for editing it. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike i can provide acess here https://script.google.com/d/1yJbQPwRzacCqQt57Bis855YgVzTW1J5YuhYsP28FVuU6kKR5vZmuJkdC/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you fo replying. Now, I edited it. Please test it again. Please redeploy Web Apps and test it again.

Comment: @Tanaike it works but i dint understand how to change U+00A0 to U+0020 is it because of my keybord settings?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `it works`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `but i dint understand how to change U+00A0 to U+0020 is it because of my keybord settings?`, unfortunately, I cannot know your environment. So I have no clear answer for your additional question. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I think that I have to study more.

Comment: As an approach, I proposed 2 methods for resolving your current issue. One is to copy and paste the HTML and CSS from your question to your project. Another is a sample script. In this case, I show a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. By this script, when HTML and CSS are loaded, `U+00A0` is replaced with `U+0020`. But, in this case, all `U+00A0` are replaced. Please be careful about this. If this was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation of `when i deploy, browser shows this`, in this case, I could notice the reason for this issue by directly checking your Google Apps Script project.

The reason for your current issue is due to that `U+00A0` (no-break space) is used as the space. When this is used, I confirmed the same situation.

In this case, please modify `U+00A0` to `U+0020`. By this, I confirmed that your CSS worked correctly. In order to do this, for example, how about copying and pasting the HTML and CSS from your question to your Google Apps Script project? By the way, when you copy and paste them, please modify the last `<style>` of your CSS to `</style>`. Please be careful about this.

#### Replacing `U+00A0` to `U+0020` using a script:

About replacing `U+00A0` to `U+0020`, for example, when you might be worried about the same situation, how about replacing them using Google Apps Script when the HTML and CSS are loaded? When this is reflected in a sample script, please modify your Google Apps Script as follows. In this case, `doGet` and `include` are modified.

```js
function doGet() {
  const str = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().getContent().replace(/\u00A0/gi, "\u0020");
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent().replace(/\u00A0/gi, "\u0020");
}
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".